# Can Firebase Crashlytics show events from Analytics?

Tags: firebase, analytics, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I set up Firebase Analytics and Firebase Crashlytics for my project.

Can I view Analytics events and user properties in Firebase Crashlytics reports (including automatically collected events)?

Should I log events for Analytics and Crashlytics independently?

Should I set user properties for Analytics and customs keys for Crashlytics independently?

It looks like duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: Crashlytics *is* now able to show Analytics events.**

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Firebase Crash Reporting and Firebase Crashlytics are fully independent products, so you will have to deal with them separately.

Crashlytics currently is not able to show Analytics events in crash reports.  That is something the team would like to add in the future.

Comment: Shoud I use Crash Reporting instead Crashlytics? But Crash Reporting page recommends me using Crashlytics.

Comment: Crashlytics is now the primary crash reporter for Firebase, but you are free to make a decision about which one to use.  On Android, you can use both at the same time, but not on iOS.

Comment: I think this is a really important feature. I have an app with quite a lot of Fragments and it is sometimes difficult to reproduce a crash because I don't know where it crashes. (because of background threads the line numbers won't really help) That's why I'm using Firebase screen tracking so I know where in my app it crashed, but this won't work with Firebase Crashlytics...